# PyQt5 QtChart ignoring rubberband on curve

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to zoom in a chart that consists from lots of sine waves close to each other, but when I accidentally click on one of the curves (they are tightly together as in the image) the rubberband isn't created and therefore the zoom is ignored, it only allows me to zoom on the white borders of the chart.

Any ideas how to fix it, so if I click on the curve then it will zoom as well?

The overrided function:

```
class aview(QChartView):
    def __init__(self, chart, parent):
        super(aview, self).__init__(chart, parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setInteractive(True)
        self.setRubberBand(self.HorizontalRubberBand)
```

Call to the overrided function:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        ...
        curve = QLineSeries()
        curve.setUseOpenGL(True)
        curve.append(.........) # this isn't important for this question
        ...
        self.current = QWidget(self)
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().hide()
        self.chart.addSeries(curve)

        self.chart_view = aview(self.chart, self.current)
        self.chart_view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Chart without zoom:
[image: not zoomed]

Horizontally zoomed chart (consisting of sinewaves):
[image: zoomed]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ekhumoro I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was OpenGL, it creates a transparent widget on top of all others which is a separate widget that can't be animated:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop

> The OpenGL acceleration of series drawing is meant for use cases that
>   need fast drawing of large numbers of points. It is optimized for
>   efficiency, and therefore the series using it lack support for many
>   features available to non-accelerated series:
>
> **Series animations are not supported for accelerated series.**
>
> ...

So simply commenting out `curve.setUseOpenGL(True)` solved it.